# replacing php form with new content on submit using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a poll with the following action

```
echo("\t<form class=\"vote\" method=\"post\" action=\"" . $url . "vote.php\">\r\n");
```

vote.php calls several validating functions and finally displays the poll results

What I want is when the submit button is pressed, using jQuery, call vote.php and display the vote result replacing the poll.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to submit your data. You can find plenty of resources if you search for it. Here's [one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

I would have vote.php echo the html for the poll results. You can then use JQuery to replace the content of the poll's div with the poll results using the [success()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, probably (untested):

```
$('.vote').submit(function()
{
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $('#insert-here').load(action, data));
});
```